# DataTable limited rows

Tags: javascript, django, html-table, datatable, datatables

I have data in my SQLite table and it has 985 rows, so I used DataTable to organise (searching and export to Pdf, CSV...), the problem is that the DataTable is limited rows and just shows the first 200 rows!.

my code is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
          $('#table_id').DataTable({
    dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
    buttons: {
        name: 'primary',
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf' ]
        }
      });
});
</script
```

the data is stored in table Sqlite

[image]

and in the HTML page:

[image]

so what's the solution with?

Comment: The question doesn't show us how data is loaded from the database to the web page. According to your DataTables code, the data must already be in a `<html>` tag in the page. So, how many rows of data are in that `<html>` table? You can inspect the page source to check that. If it's only 200 rows (which is what DataTables is reporting: `...of 200 entries`) then the information needed to solve this problem is missing from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one option for this:

You can use the [paging](https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging) option and set it to false, or you can use the [pageLength](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) option to choose how many results you want to show on one page.

`paging`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
          $('#table_id').DataTable({
    dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
    paging: false,
    buttons: {
        name: 'primary',
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf' ]
        }
      });
});
</script
```

`pageLength`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
          $('#table_id').DataTable({
    "pageLength": 1000,
    dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
    buttons: {
        name: 'primary',
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf' ]
        }
      });
});
</script
```